# error when clicking a link using ruby/watir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to ruby/watir and am getting an error when trying to click on a link.
The error is:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-classic/elemen
t.rb:328:in `assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"],
:id=>"My Link"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:474:in `perform_action'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:354:in `click!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/watir-c
lassic/element.rb:157:in `click'
        from Login.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

The link that I am trying to click looks like this:

```
<TD><DIV id=div style="DISPLAY: inline"><A id=Hyperlink href="javascript:RunFullScreen('myURL')">My Link</A></DIV>
```

Also, I tried to write out all links on the page using 'puts', but nothing was written out when the script finished
I used this code to write out the links (not sure if this is correct or not):

```
browser.links.each {|link| puts link.attribute_value("text") if link.visible?}
```

Comment: use id `:id=>"Hyperlink"` not `MyLink`

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: to view the text of all the links you should be able to use `browser.links.each {|link| puts link.text if link.visible?}`  you might want to also try that sans the visibility check.   If you don't see it at all, have a close look and verify it is not in a frame.

Answer (score 1):

The error says tat you tried to find an object with the following properties: `{:tag_name=>["a"], :id=>"My Link"}`, but you have show us HTML code with `A id=Hyperlink`. So to find out that HTML you need to specify properly its attributes:

```
 @b.element :tag_name => 'a', :id => 'Hyperlink'
```

or

```
 @b.a :id => 'Hyperlink'
```